# bookmarklet: getting current time of embedded iframe youtube player?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, bookmarklet

I am novice javascript developer. I have a bookmarklet that can get the current time of a youtube video.

```
javascript:(function(){
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
    var secs = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
    alert(`${secs}`);
})();
```

It works fine on youtube.com. However, when I apply the same logic to an iframe-based website ([url here](https://you-tldr.com/)). According to youtube API reference, I use `function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()`. but nothing happens when I run the bookmarklet. Here is the code

```
javascript:function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
   var ytplayer = new YT.Player('widget2');
   var secs = ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
   alert(`${secs}`);
}
```

Does any youtube API expert can spot the issue?

Here is the iframe of [the sample youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSWwIQzKsbY) from the website

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eSWwIQzKsbY?autoplay=1&amp;mute=0&amp;controls=1&amp;start=0&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fyou-tldr.com&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;widgetid=1" id="widget2" data-gtm-yt-inspected-1_25="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I have a similar need. I don't think you called the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` function. This is the working code.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        var player = new YT.Player('widget2', {//The id of the div containing the iframe. Should be changed based on the page you're at and the i they gave their player
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange//Event listener, fires onPlayerStateChange function whenever the state of the video changes, paused or played 
            }
        });

        function onPlayerStateChange() {
            currentTime = player.playerInfo.currentTime;//Current Time saved
            if (player.playerInfo.playerState === 2) {//If video paused, console.log the time
                console.log(currentTime);
            }
        }
    }
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();//Initial call to the function
```